# Sql query generated by entity framework contains [dbo] and is not returning any results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, sdf

I am playing around a bit with entity framework 6.1.3 in combination with EntityFramework.SQLServerCompact 6.1.3 for SQL Server Compact 4.0. I got a database with a table named SingleEntities with a few basic columns. This table got 4 rows as testdata. When I try to retrieve all 4 rows with the following code:

```
var entities = context.SingleEntities.ToList();
```

No rows are returned and no error is shown. When I check the query this code is creating, I see the this query:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Extent1].[BeginDate] AS [BeginDate], 
[Extent1].[EndDate] AS [EndDate]
FROM [dbo].[SingleEntities] AS [Extent1]
```

When I run this query directly on the database, I am getting this error:

> Error Code: 80040E14
>    Message   : The table name is not valid. [ Token line number (if known) = 7,Token line offset (if known) = 18,Table name = SingleEntities ]
>    Minor Err.: 26100
>    Source    : SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
>    Num. Par. : 7
>    Num. Par. : 18
>    Err. Par. : SingleEntities

When I remove the [dbo]. part in the query, the query gives me the result I want.

How can I tell entity framework not to add the [dbo]. part to the query? I tried to do this with an IDbCommandInterceptor but I still didn't get any result.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking up data in the correct database - please share your connection string

Comment: You are looking at the problem from the wrong angle. Is the table in the dbo schema?

Comment: @ErikEJ your answer triggered me to check again. The connection string was valid for the executable. But in my process I changed from executable to unit testing and forgot they require their own app.settings with the connection strings. So in fact, the database was empty after all.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking up data in the wrong database - please double check your connection string

Comment: This is true, like I said in an earlier answer on the question itself.